# How can I fix it: Mysql remote access not working

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I did this in mysql

```
USE mysql;

CREATE user 'test'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'test';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'test'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

and in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install ufw

sudo ufw allow mysql

sudo ufw allow 3306

service mysql restart
```

and edited mysqld.cnf in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d

```
#bind-address       = 127.0.0.1
```

but when I try to access mysql server in terminal with this code

```
mysql -utest -ptest --port 3306 --host [myip]
```

[image]

And this is 3306 port status

[image]

Comment: mysql -uroot -pPassword -h ipAddress

Comment: @John Joe same result :(

Comment: Versions of Ubuntu, ufw, mysql?  Can you connect without the firewall in place?

Comment: @RickJames ubuntu: 18.10 / ufw 0.35 / mysql: 5.7.25 and it's same result when I disabled ufw

Comment: What is the setting of `skip_name_resolve`?

Comment: @RickJames I commented out skip_name_resolve

Comment: Did you restart after changing mysqld.cnf?

Comment: @RickJames Yes I restarted...

Comment: @RickJames I think this problem related with my another question. Please check this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55032018/my-port-has-filtered-how-can-i-open-this

Comment: Does it help to un-comment-out bind-address?

Comment: @RickJames No. It wasn't working

Answer (score 1):

You have at least local access to MySQL, since you could issue a CREATE USER statement.

Using this access, inspect the `performance_schema.host_cache` table: it lists all the possible root causes for denied connections.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-perfschema-excerpt/5.7/en/host-cache-table.html

With this, with status variables, etc, your should be able to figure out whether:

- the connection is blocked in the network, not even reaching the server,
- the connection is blocked by the server itself, due to various failures affecting authentication.

Try also a simple telnet to port 3306, and see if a connection and some reply data comes back, indicating the server can be reached at least thought the network.

EDIT:

Commenting a bind-address in the cnf file is one thing, but it is better to verify which bind address is actually used by the server:

```
mysql> show variables like "%bind%";
+---------------------+-------+
| Variable_name       | Value |
+---------------------+-------+
| bind_address        | *     |
| mysqlx_bind_address | *     |
+---------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

This can affect connections.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But my host_cache table is empty. And I tried telnet command but it's not repond for long time.

Comment: @Busted in the error you got, there is "(110)" at the end, which points to the underlying socket error. 110 is ETIMEDOUT (connection timeout). To confirm, please try shutting down the server to verify, and you should get (111) ECONNREFUSED (connection refused) instead.

Comment: is this your complete my.cnf in the question above - could you post the rest? Is there maybe a "skip-networking" directive set?

Answer (score 0):

give apache remote access

**Check this answer** https://stackoverflow.com/a/55037055/7510232

Comment: Thank you but I'm not using apache. I'm using just mysql.

Comment: are you running db on a VM?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing this line indicates MySQL is listening on ipv6:

```
:::3306
```

I think MySQL is currently *only* listening on the ipv6 address (and localhost), so try to set the bind-address to the ipv4 address that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried ping the MySQL server and telnet the port?

:::3306 indicates your MySQL server is listening on both ipv4 and ipv6,
if you want to access it through ipv6, then
you need to add

```
bind-address = ::
```

to support your ipv6 access